# How to scan AWS AMI images

Tags: vulnerabilities, nexus-5

We can create custom image on AWS and what is the strategy to scan these AMI's for vulnerability check?
1) What is the tool used?
2) How vulnerability gets introduced in custom AMI?
3) Can I have docker image also as part of AMI?
4) Do AWS provide any inhouse vulnerability checking service?

Thanks in advance